# Apple Pay with Stripe show exception in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, stripe-payments, applepay

When i try to show apple pay using stripe in flutter its shows below error

PlatformException(paymentError, Failed to present payment controller, null, null)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you want to share the code and the detailed error message so that we can help to troubleshoot?

Comment: Thanks for help but i sort out problem. Problem is with Pay library becuase pay library not support UK country code

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a problem with the PaymentItems. I was using a String function to generate the prices and it was consistently throwing this error when executing `showPaymentSelector` method.